# How to migrate rabbitmq (everything) to bitnami rabbitmq cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, bitnami

How to migrate rabbitmq (everything) to bitnami rabbitmq cluster?

I have single node rabbitmq server with plenty of queues, exchanges, channels, producers and consumers.

We have a task to migrate everything of this rabbitmq server to a bitnami helm chart(https://bitnami.com/stack/rabbitmq/helm) rabbitmq with 3 node cluster, running in kubernetes cluster.

Current rabbitmq server hostname is different from what rabbitmq hostnames of three rabbitmq cluster nodes.

I'm a beginner with rabbitmq aspects.

So how do we approach this?

how to migrate data of a rabbitmq server whose hostname will be different from target rabbitmq server of bitnami helm chart cluster?